# i can't make a button that play scene2 from scene1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

i make a button navigate from scene1 to scene2 then when i creat swf from fla it's like a loop the play scene1 and scene2 together.
    button_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_2);

```
function fl_ClickToGoToScene_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to put a `stop()` in your current frame in scene 1 when you start scene 3.